# JDBC ilike query java

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

JDBC successfully connected to PostgreSQL. But some ilike query still have problems. only 1 code is working. I want the first and the third one to working properly.

--------------- not working

```
String ilikequery = "SELECT * FROM emp where ? iLIKE '%C%' ";
PreparedStatement ilikestatement = Main.connection.prepareStatement(ilikequery);
ilikestatement.setString(1,"name");
ResultSet resultSet = ilikestatement.executeQuery();
```

-------------- this one working,

```
String queryname = "Cowen";
 String query = "select * from emp where name = ?";
PreparedStatement  statement = Main.connection.prepareStatement(query);
 statement.setString(1,queryname);
ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
```

------------this one not working.

```
String ilikequerywithparameter = "SELECT * FROM emp" + " where name iLIKE '%"+"?"+"%' ";
PreparedStatement ilikestatementpara = Main.connection.prepareStatement(ilikequerywithparameter);
 ilikestatementpara.setString(1,"c");
 ResultSet resultSet = ilikestatementpara.executeQuery();
```

The last code snippet have Exception error.`Exception in thread "main" org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column index is out of range: 1, number of columns:`

-------- this one is working.

```
String simpleilikequery = "SELECT * FROM emp" + " WHERE name iLIKE '%C%'";
PreparedStatement simpleilikestatement = Main.connection.prepareStatement(simpleilikequery);
ResultSet resultSet = simpleilikestatement.executeQuery();
```

Comment: I'm not sure how `where ? iLIKE '%C%'` is suppose to work. The wildcard is referring to a column name?  I'd expect something more like `where name iLIKE ?` to be the correct format

Comment: name is one of the column.  but I just want to try to use setString mathod. So I can sue setString easily change to another column.

Comment: Your first query passes the value `'name'` to the parameter, not a column name (you can't specify column names through parameters, only values). Your third query produces a string literal `'%?%'`, that is a string with a question mark, which is a not a parameter placeholder.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the wildcards as part of the parameter, not the prepared statement:

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM emp where name iLIKE ?";
PreparedStatement stmt = Main.connection.prepareStatement(ilikequerywithparameter);
stmt.setString(1,"%c%");
```

Or alternatively use `concat()` in the SQL string if you don't want to (or can't) modify the parameter itself.

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM emp where name iLIKE concat('%', ?, '%')";
PreparedStatement stmt = Main.connection.prepareStatement(ilikequerywithparameter);
stmt.setString(1,"c");
```

Comment: Yes. The second one working. It's so COOL>